# Select statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i don't know what is that error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Resource id #3' at line 1

any help please?

```
<?php
//Connecting to sql db.

if(!($database=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") ))

    die(mysql_error()); 

if(!mysql_select_db("Ehab",$database) )
    die(mysql_error()); 

//Sending form data to sql db.
if(isset($_POST["websites"]))
    //html klma
    $sitesphp=$_POST["websites"];

if(isset($_POST["description"]))
    $descriptionphp=$_POST["description"];

$query= "INSERT INTO website (sites, des) VALUES ('$sitesphp','$descriptionphp')";

//take query and then put it down 
//in result

if(!($result=mysql_query($query,$database)))
    {
        print("etla3 bara ya homar");
        die(mysql_error()); 
    }?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Database Update</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Database successfully updated.</h1>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>URL</th><th>description</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    //error occurs here
    if ( !( $result = mysql_query( "SELECT sites,des FROM website", $database ) ) )
        {
            print( "<p>Could not execute query!</p>" );
            die( mysql_error() );
        }

mysql_close( $database );

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $result ) )
    print( "<tr><td>" . $row[ 0 ] . "</td><td>" . $row[ 1 ] . "</td></tr>" );
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no error in this code. It may be in some other part of your code.

Comment: What does your database look like?

Comment: SIDENOTE: you are **VERY WIDE** open to sql injections. And If the error is really in this file it is your insert query causing issues, should be something with the values you're  trying to insert which returns us to the SIDENOTE :)

Comment: @user3597606 Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of the file to display the error.

Comment: That error would happen if you were substituting an incorrect variable, like `$database` or `$result` into the argument to `mysql_query()`. But both your queries look OK in this regard.

Comment: Print your variables $sitesphp and $descriptionphp and make sure they are returning what you expect.

Comment: @AbuSulaiman It's very unlikely that they would contain `Resource id #3`. And he's quoting them in the query, so it wouldn't cause this error even if they did.

Comment: Which call to `mysql_query` is causing the error?

Comment: @Barmar so basically it is either the variables or not this file...

Comment: I think it's not this file, as Rahul said

Comment: if description is `this is a website' Resource Id #3` this error would happen

Comment: Actually, it would complain about the `s`.

Comment: @Barmar Updated :P was just an example...

Comment: Yes, it's possible to intentionally construct ways to make this happen. I consider it so unlikely in the real world that it's not worth discussing.

Answer (score 1):

I would not place the

```
 mysql_fetch_row()
```

after

```
  mysql_close()
```

because I guess the result is empty after closing the connection. Perhaps this is also the origin for the "missing resource" as it is already closed.

Btw as far as I remember the error comes from the SQL not from the php so line 1 is not line 1 of the php file but the line 1 of the SQL statement.

Comment: +1 for the good eye, although this is an SQL error

Comment: Yes I agree this is an SQL error. Just appended my answere :-)